# Issue with inline variable initialization vs sequential initialization

Tags: python

I am trying to write a small script that judges if the contents of a linked list are a palindrome.

The following code works:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def linkify(lst):
    LL = ListNode(val=lst[0],next=None)
    node = LL
    for i,v in enumerate(lst[1:]):
        node.next = ListNode(val=v,next=None)
        node = node.next
    return LL
k = 5
lst1 = [i for i in range(k)] + [i for i in reversed(range(k))]
list1 = linkify(lst1)
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,2,1]
list2 = linkify(lst2)

def isPalindrome(head):
        rev = None
        slow = fast = head
        
        while fast and fast.next:
            fast = fast.next.next
            rev, rev.next, slow = slow, rev, slow.next
            
        if fast:
            slow = slow.next
            
        while rev:
            if slow.val != rev.val:
                return False                
            else:
                slow, rev = slow.next, rev.next
        return not rev

print("Is list1 a palindrome?") 
print("Answer: ", isPalindrome(list1))
print("Is list2 a palindrome?") 
print("Answer: ", isPalindrome(list2))
```

I wanted to modify the code and so I tried instead doing

```
def isPalindrome(head):
        rev = None
        slow = fast = head
        
        while fast and fast.next:
            fast = fast.next.next
            rev = slow 
            rev.next = rev
            slow = slow.next
        if fast:
            slow = slow.next
            
        while rev:
            if slow.val != rev.val:
                return False                
            else:
                slow, rev = slow.next, rev.next
        return not rev
```

But this version fails and it times out. It just keeps running.

Can someone explain why changing

```
rev, rev.next, slow = slow, rev, slow.next
```

to

```
rev = slow 
rev.next = rev
slow = slow.next
```

changes things so dramatically? I thought these would be equivalent.

Comment: You would need to create temporary variables for `slow` and `rev`, consider the simpler case of `x, y = y, x`, you need something like `temp = y` then `y = x` and `x = temp`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for replying. Can you elaborate on why this is necessary?  I believe you, I just want to make sure I understand so I can do better in the future.

Comment: So, again, just think about the simplest case, `x = 0; y = 42` if you do `x = y` than `y = x`, well, you just assigned `x = 42`, but then when you do `y = x`, *`x == 42`* so you end up with both `x` and `y` equaling 42. Now work through what happens if you use the `temp` variable. It's a classic idiom in languages like C, Java etc. But Python has another way that works because in `x, y = y, x`, the right-hand-side is fully evaluated before the values are assigned to the left hand side

Comment: Wow, really nicely explained! I had no idea about that. Would you like to put that in an answer so I can upvote and accept?